# C# Dynamic form (reflection) - linking controls

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, reflection, user-controls

Sorry for the poor quality of the title. I couldn't think of a better way to phrase this.

For a project I'm currently working on with a few friends, I got myself in the situation where I have created a dynamic form (with reflection) which I now want to validate.

Example (ignore the black box, it contains old form elements which are now irrelevant and i didn't want to confuse you guys):

[image: Dynamic form with reflection]

As you may have guessed already, it is an application for creating a mysql database.
Which is where I get to my problem(s). I want to disable checkboxes if others are checked.

For example: If I check "PrimaryKey" I want to disable the checkbox "Null".
Changing from unsigned to signed changes the numericupdown minimum and maximum etc.

But with reflection and all, I find it difficult to know exactly which checkbox to disable.
I was hoping you guys would have some suggestions.

I have been thinking about this for a while and a few thoughts have come to mind. Maybe these are better solutions than the current one.

Thought 1: I create UserControls for every datatype. Pro's: no problems with reflection and easy identifying of every control in the UserControl for validation. Con's: Copy-Pasting, Lots of UserControls, with a lot of the same controls.

Thought 2: Doing something with the description tags for every property of the classes. Creating rules in the description that allow me to link the checkboxes together. Here I'll only have to copy the rules to every class property and then it should be ok.

I had been thinking of other solutions but I failed to remember them.
I hope you guys can give me a few good pointers/suggestions.

[Edit]
Maybe my code can explain a bit more.
My code:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = DataTypes.DataTypes.GetTypeFromString(modelElement.DataType.ToString()).GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
        {
            if (prop.Name != "Label" && prop.Name != "Project" && prop.Name != "Panel")
            {
                var value = prop.GetValue(modelElement.DataType, null);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = prop.Name, Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });

                    switch (value.GetType().ToString())
                    {
                        case "System.Int32":
                            NumericUpDown numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
                            numericUpDown.Text = value.ToString();
                            numericUpDown.Dock = DockStyle.None;
                            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(numericUpDown);

                            break;
                        case "System.Boolean":
                            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                            checkBox.Dock = DockStyle.None;

                            // checkbox will become huge if not for these changes
                            checkBox.AutoSize = false;
                            checkBox.Size = new Size(16, 16);

                            if (value.Equals(true))
                            {
                                checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                            }
                            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(checkBox);

                            break;
                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show(@"The following type has not been implemented yet: " + value.GetType());

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Heh, much easier to do in WPF. That said, do you have some sort of application model separation? As in, are you using something like MVC/MVP/MVVM/MV* ? If you have your business logic tied into the form itself, then yeah that's going to make this difficult. If you separate that logic into a separate unit, you'll find this problem much easier to solve.

Comment: it looks like that you don't have access to the form?

Comment: @sircodesalot moving to `WPF` is not easy, sometimes we have to deal with the existing project with limited time.

Comment: Why do you find it difficult to know which checkbox to disable? You can use the tag value to identify the checkbox easily.

Comment: @KingKing. Definitely understand that. The main point is that you need to separate concepts here. That is: You should seriously consider creating a class whose sole purpose is to manage how content is presented on the UI (A **'ViewModel'**). It's job should be to handle the sort of visual logic in your question. Then have it expose properties like "IsTheIsNullBoxVisible" and so forth. Then, in your UI, have it respond to changes in your 'ViewModel', if 'IsTheIsNullBoxVisible' is false, then the box shouldn't show, and vice-versa. Separate visual logic (*VM*) from the final presentation (*UI*).

Comment: @sircodesalot We currently have no application model separation (its a first draft).

Alright then. I'll go about creating a ViewModel for this purpose. See where that gets me.

Comment: Oh, I guess I should respond to Orion, heh oops. I wrote up a mockup below that essentially explains the concepts involved.

Comment: @Orion the most confusing thing here is you talk about `Reflection` but I don't think you need any `Reflection` here, your problem may be something related to `create form dynamically`. `Reflection` is just for dealing with an object of a type which we can't add custom code to modify how it works or invoke its members...

Comment: @kingking this can be resolved in WPF with a simple `DataTemplate` and not having to deal with all that horrible reflection stuff.

Comment: @Orion as previously mentioned, this is really easier (actually all the boilerplate and piping and reflection and hacks are eliminated) in WPF. I strongly suggest you consider that if you need such a dynamic functionality. Using relevant non-obsolete .Net Windows Desktop UI technologies you can do this in no-time. If you are interested, I can provide a simple example of how to implement this in a strogly-typed, type-safe, less-code manner in WPF.

Comment: I think the MVVM solution might be a great solution for me @King King

I have a Model(database table) and a UserControl which it is displayed "on". For each Model property I need to be able to show an Edit dialog, as seen in the image above. 

I want to have a dynamic form on which I can display all the properties I could possibly have. up to 12 different types!.

Having to create a form for all the different types is not a solution I would like to go for. Also having looked into MVVM this appears to be almost what I'd have to do. I'm going to see if I can develop a solution that works for me.

Comment: @orion be warned that winforms does not (natively) support any kind of MVVM, since it's databinding is really limited and does not offer the advanced databinding capabilities required by MVVM. Also, winforms does not have any equivalent of `DataTemplates`, which are really required in a situation like this.

Comment: I think KingKing's point is valid though. WPF is a learning curve, and I don't recommend it if you're on a super tight deadline. It's conceptually *VERY* different from WinForms (which is why it's so much better IMHO) and you should expect to spend a bit before it really starts to click.

Comment: @sircodesalot given the OP's current requirement, I think time spent in learning WPF and creating some 5 ViewModels and a couple of DataTemplates could be shorter than trying to hack something useful thru the limitations of winforms.

Comment: @HighCore no way to disagree with abandoning suck-technology (WinForms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mockup from my comments:

```
// The ViewModel is responsible for handling the actual visual layout of the form.
public class ViewModel {

    // Fire this when your ViewModel changes
    public event EventHandler WindowUpdated;

    public Boolean IsIsNullCheckBoxVisible { get; private set; }

    // This method would contain the actual logic for handling window changes.
    public void CalculateFormLayout() {

        Boolean someLogic = true;

        // If the logic is true, set the isNullCheckbox to true
        if (someLogic) {
            IsIsNullCheckBoxVisible = true;
        }

        // Inform the UI to update
        UpdateVisual();
    }

    // This fires the 'WindowUpdated' event.
    public void UpdateVisual() {
        if (WindowUpdated != null) {
            WindowUpdated(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

}

public class TheUI : Form {

    // Attach to the viewModel;
    ViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModel();
    CheckBox isNullCheckBox = new CheckBox();

    public TheUI() {
        this.myViewModel.WindowUpdated += myViewModel_WindowUpdated;
    }

    void myViewModel_WindowUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Update the view here.

        // Notie that all we do in the UI is to update the visual based on the
        // results from the ViewModel;
        this.isNullCheckBox.Visible = myViewModel.IsIsNullCheckBoxVisible;
    }

}
```

The basic idea here is that you ensure that the UI does *as little as possible*. It's role should just be to update. Update what? That's for the `ViewModel` class to decide. We perform all of the updating logic in the `ViewModel` class, and then when the updating computations are done, we call the `UpdateVisual()` event, which tells the UI that it needs to represent itself. When the `WindowUpdated` Event occurs, the UI just responds by displaying the configuration set up by the `ViewModel`.

This may seem like a lot of work to set up initially, but once in place it will save you tons and tons of time down the road. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try relating the event of one checkbox to disable the other; something like this:

```
private void primaryKeyBox_AfterCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nullBox.Enabled = false;
}
```

This is a very simple example and would have to be changed a bit, but for what I think you're asking it should work. You would also have to add to an event for the boxes being unchecked. You would also need logic to only get data from certain checkboxes based on the ones that are and are not checked.

For all the other things, such as changing the numbers based on the dropdown, change them based on events as well.

Answer (score -1):

For WinForms I would use data binding.

Create an object and implement INotifyPropertyChanged and work with that object.

Then, If you have an object instance aObj:

To bind the last name property to a textbox on the form do this:

```
Private WithEvents txtLastNameBinding As Binding

txtLastNameBinding = New Binding("Text", aObj, "LastName", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "")

txtLastName.DataBindings.Add(txtLastNameBinding)
```

Take a look here for more info.
[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. And it doesn't solve the fact that winforms doesn't have anything like WPF's `DataTemplates`, which are the easiest way to do this.

Comment: He can separate his business logic from the ui and handle any case he wants without having to use reflection.

Comment: this does not explain how would the OP deal with complex scenarios such as hiding a certain UI element depending on some complex condition involving one or MORE property values in the underlying model, something you could do easily with WPF via `<DataTemplate.Triggers/>`.

Comment: To get a working solution he COULD bind to the visibility properties of the control based on conditions since an update to the client occurs when a property is changed on the object. BUT, I do believe WPF is best for this as long as he has the time to learn it. I was assuming he was looking at WinForms and I didn't explain myself fully. But it is an option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301848/mvp-in-winforms